# Custom round off logic

Tags: sql-server

One of my customers is asking for the following rounding logic.  Want to check if there is anyway straightforward way of doing this in SQL.

- 0 to 0.49 - round to 0
- 0.5 to 0.54 - round to 0.50
- 0.55 to 1.00 - round to 1.00

Thank

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/bankers-rounding-in-t-sql-like-math-round-in-net

Answer (score 3):

**You can use a bunch of `CASE` conditions with modulo division `%`**

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN YourValue % 1.0 < 0.5
      THEN FLOOR(YourValue)
    WHEN YourValue % 1.0 >= 0.55
      THEN CEILING(YourValue)
    WHEN YourValue % 1.0 BETWEEN 0.5 AND 0.55
      THEN FLOOR(YourValue) + 0.5
    END
FROM YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de91f3137808eb97cd46b2f3612f32b2)

If there are no nulls you change the last condition to `ELSE`

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN YourValue % 1.0 < 0.5
      THEN FLOOR(YourValue)
    WHEN YourValue % 1.0 >= 0.55
      THEN CEILING(YourValue)
    ELSE
      FLOOR(YourValue) + 0.5
    END
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Given how every rule is specified explicitly, it makes perfect sense to implement the logic with one `CASE` branch per rule, as [done by the other answerer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/297347).  Such an approach makes it easier to add changes to the code whenever a particular rule is changed.

On the other hand, if the rules are never expected to go too crazy, you could also take advantage of the fact that the first and third rules are using the regular rounding logic, and therefore implement them in a single branch:

```
CASE
  WHEN YourValue % 1.0 < 0.5 OR YourValue % 1.0 >= 0.55 THEN
    ROUND(YourValue, 0)
  ELSE
    FLOOR(YourValue) + 0.5
END
```

And since now we are down to just two alternatives, it will be convenient to use the `IIF` shorthand for this:

```
IIF(YourValue % 1.0 < 0.5 OR YourValue % 1.0 >= 0.55
  , ROUND(YourValue, 0)
  , FLOOR(YourValue) + 0.5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a CLR function:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
[return: SqlFacet(Precision = 18, Scale = 2)]
public static SqlDecimal fn_round([SqlFacet(Precision = 18, Scale = 2)] decimal value)
{
    var dec = (int)(((decimal)value % 1) * 100);
    decimal result = 0m;

    if (dec < 50)
        result = (decimal)((int)value);
    else if (dec >= 55)
        result = (decimal)((int)value) + 1.0m;
    else
        result = ((decimal)((int)value)) + 0.50m;

    return new SqlDecimal(result);
}
```

Create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_round](@value [numeric](18, 2))
RETURNS [numeric](18, 2) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [yourDB].[Functions].[fn_round]
GO
```

And use it in this way:

```
declare @d1 decimal(18,2) = dbo.fn_round(13.45);
declare @d2 decimal(18,2) = dbo.fn_round(13.53);
declare @d3 decimal(18,2) = dbo.fn_round(13.57);

select @d1 AS [< 0.5],  @d2 AS [> 0.5 < 0.55], @d3 AS [>= 0.55];
```

| < 0.5 | > 0.5 < 0.55 | >= 0.55 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13.00 | 13.50 | 14.00 |

If your customer change his mind, simply change the function.